# PHP. Foreach 4000 elements Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm a newbie at php, however I managed to get an array with 4000 elements 1000arrays × 4elements

I need to create a ForEach loop so it 'allocates' my 'folder', 'path', 'artist', 'title' correctly 1000 times.

```
<?php 
return array(
  array('folder' => 'A-Ha', 'path' => 'A-Ha/A-ha - Song1.mp3', 'artist' => 'A-Ha', 'title' => 'Song1') ,
  array('folder' => 'U-2', 'path' => 'U-2/U-2 - Song2.mp3', 'artist' => 'U-2', 'title' => 'Song2') ,
  array(' ...1000more arrays with four elements ... );
?>


<?php
$counter = 0;
echo '<a name="'.$counter.'"></a>
<li><span class="playb" rel="'.$p[$counter]['path'].'">

<span class="folder">'.$p[$counter]['folder'].'</span>
<span class="artist">'.$p[$counter]['artist'].' - </span>
<span class="title">'.$p[$counter]['title'].'</span>

</span></li>'; $counter++;?>
```

So what I want to get in the END [html]:

```
<a name="0"></a>
<li><span class="playb" rel="A-Ha/A-Ha - Song1.mp3">
<span class="folder">A-Ha</span>
<span class="artist">A-Ha - </span>
<span class="title">Song1</span>
</span></li>


<a name="1"></a>
<li><span class="playb" rel="U-2/U-2 - Song2.mp3">
<span class="folder">U-2</span>
<span class="artist">U-2 - </span>
<span class="title">Song2</span>
</span></li>
```

and 1000 songs more...

IM SO GLAD -- Ben Fortune read my question!
Thank you to the rest of those who tried, I really appreciate it guys. And I perfectly imagine how hard .... impossible it was to understand the first edit of the question.
Thanks Ben and every1 else! Peace!

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ? what do you mean by 'allocates' ?

Comment: What do you mean by allocate? What are you wanting to do with the data? How are you getting the data in the first place?

Comment: i think he wants to know how to buuild an array of 4000 elements, each a sub array with 4 elements. @Anton what is your data source?

Comment: Did you put in the elements by hand? :D
I'd suggest to put the rows into a database, it looks like you want to list or search through, use MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: Better create a class and then do this...its not an optimised way to do this

Comment: Oh come on! I'm here, added a block to my question with little explanation of final look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't really have much to go on, as you haven't specified where or how you're getting your initial data. And you haven't really explained if you want to add your data to an array, or get your data from an array.

This will loop through so you can access the data.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($p as $value){
    echo '<a name="'.$counter++.'"></a>'.
         '<li>'.
             '<span class="playb" rel="'.$value['path'].'">'.    
                 '<span class="folder">'.$value['folder'].'</span>'.
                 '<span class="artist">'.$value['artist'].' - </span>'.
                 '<span class="title">'.$value['title'].'</span>'.    
             '</span>'.
         '</li>';
}
```

Comment: This looks logical, however I'm not completely sure how to use this. Have you looked at my "edits"?

Comment: How are you getting your initial data? Is it from a database or is it hard-coded somewhere?

Comment: I made it myself with Regular Expressions - it's contained by the list.php file

Comment: I've edited the first example, assume the `while` part is your loop. Instead of echoing it out into the HTML you had, add it to the array. You can check if it worked by using `print_r($data);` outside the loop.

Comment: while($p - im not sure what to put here..){ - 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes)'

Comment: It's just pseudo-code, the actual code will be the loop you're using to go through your data.(Your regex and the loop to go through the array that was created containing your regex results).

Comment: <?php $p = require 'list.php';?>
(i mentioned that in the question 'code' sections)
and that list.php was hand-made by me

Comment: And what does `list.php` contain?

Comment: <?php 
return array(
   array(... pls scroll top to the question [first code block]

Comment: Alright, now I'm lost. Are you just wanting to display the data?

Comment: ok then I will change the question so it becomes bigger and less complicated

Comment: [link](http://antonfrolov.net/php.php)
IT WORKED! 
However it created 4256 <li> items when 1064 was expected. BUT THAT IS A PROGERESS ALREADY!

Comment: Just realised my mistake, try again. :)

Comment: JESUS!! GOD!!!!! SCOTTY< JESSUS MAN!!! FINALLY SOME1 UNDERSTOOD ME! HUURRRRRAAAAAAAAAAY AND IT FINALLY WORKED !!!!111!!! YOOOHOOOO

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'd suggest you start using some sort of database, even a flatfile such as a CSV file. I can't imagine manually creating 1000+ arrays being very nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $arr){
    echo 'Folder : '.$arr['folder'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Path : '.$arr['path'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Artist : '.$arr['artist'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Title : '.$arr['title'].'<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'inner' arrays seem to be more like a dictionary with keys, which are probably much more convenient to use than a foreach loop. So that leaves you with a single loop to process all items. Something like this:

```
// Iterate through all items in the main array.
foreach($songArray as $songItem)
{

  $folder = $songItem['folder'];
  $path = $songItem['path'];
  $title = $songItem['title'];

  // Use at will
  echo $title . '<br>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand completely what you want to do, but you can parse your array this way:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  array('folder' => '28 Days Later', 'path' => '28 Days Later/28 Days Later - Ave Maria.mp3', 'artist' => '28 Days Later', 'title' => 'Ave Maria') ,
  ...
  arrays
  ...
  array('folder' => '28 Days Later', 'path' => '28 Days Later/28 Days Later - Grandaddy.mp3', 'artist' => '28 Days Later', 'title' => 'Grandaddy')
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $element)
{
  echo '<li>' , $element['folder'] , '</li>';
  echo '<li>' , $element['path'] , '</li>';
  echo '<li>' , $element['artist'] , '</li>';
  echo '<li>' , $element['title'] , '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I hope this helps you understand, please ask if something is still unclear.